# Prevent reset of subsection counters in unnumbered sections in KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script, counters, unnumbered-sections

I'm using `scrartcl` and trying to mix and match numbered and unnumbered sections and sub-sections.  It appears that in `scrartcl` the unnumbered variants of `\section` still reset the counters for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`, however I would like to prevent that from happening.  The standard `article` document class works how I'd expect.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=letter,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\subsection{SubSection 1.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\section*{Section with no Number}

\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

[image: scrartcl example]

Here's the example with standard article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\subsection{SubSection 1.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\section*{Section with no Number}

\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

[image: article example]

I've played around with various options but I do not want the un-numbered variants to appear in the ToC.  I thought about using `\minisec` but I need to support the different levels of text sizing available from the section header types.

Happy to take other suggestions on ways to handle these `\minisec`-like annotations at various levels if that makes more contextual sense than trying to avoid the counter resets.  I also eventually want to use `hyperref` to link ToC entries to sections (but kept that out of them we for simplicity), so any solution would ideally be compatible with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the compatibility option `version=3.30`:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=12pt,
  version=3.30% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\subsection{SubSection 1.1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\addsec*{Section with no Number}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you define new section commands:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\sectionnumdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  font=\usekomafont{section},
  tocstyle=gobble% because there will be no ToC entry
]{mysection}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\subsectionnumdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  font=\usekomafont{subsection},
  tocstyle=gobble% because there will be no ToC entry
]{mybubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\subsection{SubSection 1.1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\mysection*{Section with no Number}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection 1.1.2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm leaning towards defining new sections but appreciate you pointing out the other compatibility option as well.  This works great.